# How to select second or third level directory names to style

Tags: php, select, tree, styles, directory

I am trying to create a directory tree to display for a product page.IT looks thru the main directory and finds the Categories Collections, loose diamonds and tennis bracelets. The collection directory will have quite a few sub directories and those may have some as well. What i am trying to figure out is how to detect/select when the directory that is is being looked at how a subdirectory or sub directories so that i may apply a different style to the directory name. For example I would have the sub directories indented or something.

Below is teh snippet of code that i was able to find on SO. I tried adding a second while just after the filetype line in an attempt to see if i could manually set a sub file variable and look to see if the sub directory has any directories in it. I broke it when i did that:(

```
$dir = "Images/Categories/";
function recurseDirs($main, $count=0){
$dirHandle = opendir($main);
while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
    if(filetype($main.$file."/")=="dir" && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
        echo "<li>$file</li>";
        $count = recurseDirs($main.$file."/",$count); // Correct call and fixed counting
    }
}
return $count;
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you did not understand how recursion works. You want to read about that.

Comment: That really doesn't help me out. Could you perhaps point me in the direction of reference material relevant to my question?